# How to read blob image file converted using url.createobjecturl using opencv in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, opencv

after fetching image file from the local folder I convert it using url.createObjecturl for rendering purpose. Now I want to read this file using opencv imread function. but opencv imread function does not take such file.

variable contains = blob:http://localhost:3000/3984a709-43ba-49cl-9075-e6b6923a75e2